# Any idea why run any grails application increese fan speed

Tags: ubuntu, grails, cpu-usage

When I start any grails application my fans start spinning very fast. the fault lies with a java process created by grails, if i pause it, in fact the situation returns to normal. I use grails 3.1.1 and latest ubuntu. note that the same application on windows doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Do you have more details that you can add here?

Answer (score 0):

Your fans are tied to your system's internal temperature, which is increased by high CPU usage, high disk usage, etc.

Comment: Before i start the application, fan speed is normal.

Comment: Starting an application uses CPU, disk, etc.

Comment: We don't know how many applications you have running in the background, your system specs, etc. This is not an issue with Grails.

Comment: Please understand that this has nothing to do with grails; it is simply your computer doing what it is supposed to do.  Starting a grails application apparently uses a lot of CPU, or does a lot of disk access.  Anything you do with a computer can cause it to heat up, and the fans are designed to spin up faster when the computer heats up.  If you would like more information on this, I recommend google.

Comment: But if i pause one grails process, the fan speed (CPU usage, etc) returns to normal, and the application work fine. The only things that stop is the grails logger.